# Can't prevent Maven deploy plugin from publishing artefact to nexus without version timestamp suffix

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I want to publish my project's artefact .jar to my nexus repository. However the maven `deploy` plugin always includes a timestamp suffix to the deployed artefact. I followed the documentation to omit the suffix but nothing works - it's still adding it.

The documentation states that `<uniqueVersion></uniqueVersion>` should be set to `false` which I did in the `pom.xml` for every repository configuration and I also used it as a flag like so `mvn deploy -DuniqueVersion=false`. However nothing works.

The result in Nexus always has the mentioned suffix

[image]

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.company.tools.myTool</artifactId>
  <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
      <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
      <version>9.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Corporate Repository</name>
      <url>http://192.168.141.10:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Corporate Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://192.168.141.10:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Any idea what I am missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: Try to use `v3.0.0-M2` and make sure deploy new versions each time (do not override already deployed version)

Comment: Thats just how Maven snapshots work - how would you expect a Maven repository to distinguish different versions of a snapshot but with using a timestamped version internally? And from the clients point of view it's just `1.3-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Change your version from `1.3-SNAPSHOT` into `1.3` (release!)

Comment: Also remove the execution for maven-deploy-plugin which is defined by the default life cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `<uniqueVersion></uniqueVersion>` was deprecated in Maven 2.x, and removed entirely in Maven 3.  So this is not expected to work, unless you are using the EOL Maven 2.  See “major version upgrade to version 3.0” here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/